# How to authorize viewing and clicking a function only logged users?

Tags: plugins, php

I am creating a plugin that allow the users logged to favorite the posts. At first, I create a shortcode for put in the posts.

```
function add_favorite_shortcode() {
        global $post_id;
        $post_id = get_post();
        $post_id = !empty( $post_id ) ? $post_id->ID : false;
        $output = '<div class="redimensionar"><a id="teste" href="?faction=add&amp;postid='. $post_id .'" title="teste" rel="nofollow">♥ Favorito</a></div>';
        return $output;
     }
     add_shortcode( 'favorito', 'add_favorite_shortcode' );
```

Now, I would like the enable this function only for users logged, how to do it?

I found this function,

```
function only_authorised_rest_access( $result )
    {
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'rest_unauthorised', __( 'Only authenticated users can access the REST API.', 'rest_unauthorised' ), array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() ) );
        }

        return $result;
    }
    add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', 'only_authorised_rest_access');
```

but is not working to me

Comment: the action that handles this ( `?faction=add` etc ) is missing from your code. Even if you hide it anybody could directly hit that URL, and they could pass any post ID they want to favourite any post they want and ignore your shortcode and shortcode function

Comment: Yes, that is why I would like to fix it. How to fix it? Have a way to authorize only the users logged?

Comment: The `rest_authentication_errors` filter you found and edited into your question is completely unrelated to your problem, however, it contains the answer, which was also posted below by Catherine.

Comment: Also your endpoints security problem is a separate question, you should not expand your question to add extra things, it's unfair to people who answered the question, and very, very confusing to new people who find it. If you have a new or additional question, ask it separately via the Ask Question button ( and share the code you're using when you do it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the output of this shortcode from users who aren't logged in, I'd make use of the [is_user_logged_in() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) built right into Wordpress.

The issue you'll run into, however, as Tom pointed out in the comments, is that you will need to check if users are logged in as part of the action that runs to favorite the post. Hiding the button doesn't actually prevent users from using the action unless you protect the action itself as well.

Comment: I found a function from intenet for solve my problem, but unfortunately is no working. I puted the function in the main post above!

Comment: @RodrigoFranco did this not answer your question? _If not why not?_